How to overide flutter BottomNavigationBar widget with a custom container widget?
I'm using scaffold to use bottom navigation bar. There is a page where i need to change the bottom navigation bar widget into a custom widget like image below on a state changed. How can i do this?
from this

to this

I didn't found how to solve this, so please help and tell me how to do this in flutter/Dart.

Maybe add the state management to the page that has the scaffold and based on a boolean change the bottomNavbar

The BottomNavigationBar widget only can be filled with BottomNavigationBarItem. So i can't put a Container widget in the bottomNavigationBar section. @SilkeNL

you can directly use custom widget in bottomNavigationBar: customWidget(), as it accepts Widget so you can create customWidget() as per your need of type Widget

And for a placeholder you could just make a BottomNavigationBarItem with a transparent icon

Oh thankyou, i didn't know it accepts Widget. It solve the problem, thanks @HitarthChhunchha

You can directly use custom widget in bottomNavigationBar: customWidget()
bottomNavigationBar accepts type Widget? so you can create customWidget() as per your need
As per your image reference:
Widget customWidget() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            "Select Photo",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        Icon(Icons.delete),
      ],
    );
  }

